# Make a backward compatible project in Visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

At school we are using Visual Studio 2015 but at home I have Visual studio 2017. When I start project at home there is a lot of error happening when I get back to school.

Our homeworks are made so they can both be made in the two versions. So is there any way I could se a parameter so my projects made with 2017 version of visual could be fully compatible with the 2015 version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Restrict your VS 2017 to C++11 or C++14 *only* (can't remember which VS2015 supports). Can be done with compiler options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set VS 2017 to use the compiler from VS 2015 pretty easily. Bring up the project settings page and choose "Visual Studio 2015 (v140)" for the "Platform Toolset":

[image]

So even though you're using the VS 2017 IDE, you're still using the VS 2015 compiler, so if you write any code that won't work with VS 2015, you'll find out about it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to have your C++ source code in a separate folder from your project files.   That is you have two different solutions:

`c:\projects\YourProject\Src` (Your source code goes here)

`c:\projects\YourProjects\VS2015` (Create a Visual Studio 2015 in this directory and add files from ..\Src here)

`c:\projects\YourProjects\VS2017` (reate a Visual Studio 2015 in this directory and add files from ..\Src here)

This comes with the slight annoyance that you'd have to maintain two sets of project files. But I'm guessing for homework, you just need a handful of source files and not a lot (if any) project customizations beyond just adding source files to it.

Comment: how does this help with the compatibility issue? How does this help him see in VS2017 errors that he would get in VS2015?

Comment: I suspect, for the complexity of his homework assignments, the differences in C++ compatibility between the two compilers will be so minor (if observed at all) that it will be simple to get the code to cross-compile.